# my unittest passes but says zero percent coverage

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wrote a unittest for my model, the test passes but it says I have zero percent coverage. Any advice would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant snippets of the code as text and not as images.

Comment: Also: `models.py` is defining the model class. So I don't think it's actually possible to hit those parts with a unit test in any relevant way. 100% coverage isn't a particularly good goal. Better to test the business logic where you use those models instead.

Comment: @salient  okay thank you, I will just ignore testing that file then.

Comment: @salient  I'm not sure it will let me award you any points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/180), models are already imported before test command is executed because of app configuration process. Try to apply the [patch](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/180#issuecomment-93371418) given by [eliangcs](https://github.com/eliangcs).